# char not converting to string in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I am trying to make a program that concatenate characters cast from ints into Strings and then puts those strings into an array and prints them. I have tried a few different ways to make characters into string including Character.toString() ,StringBuilders and adding "". Yet,whenever I print to the console in eclipse I just get question marks instead of letters. How can I solve this. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            char b = (char)2;
            String god = Character.toString(b);
            System.out.println(god);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Casting an int to a char in Java will use the Ascii code that int represents.

The Ascii code 2 is not a printable character, hence why you are getting question marks. You can see a list of Ascii codes [here](http://www.asciitable.com)

I presume what you wanted to do is use '2' instead. (Note the quotation marks.)

```
char b = '2';
```

Comment: no I want a char that corresponds to a number and I thought casting would be the best way compared to selecting from a sting or array.

Comment: @user4485835 To get a char for a number, you just need to place that number in quotation marks, no casting needed. eg char b = '2';

Comment: like how "a" corresponds to 1

Comment: @user4485835 Weirdly, no. Internally, chars are represented by numbers. You can find which number corresponds to which char by looking at the Ascii table I linked to. Counterintuitively, if you do System.out.println((int) 'a'); in Java, you'll actually get 97, because the Ascii value for 'a' is 97 not 1. Then 'b' is 98, c is '99' etc. The values before this represent things like punctuation.